# Spring Controller / leading/trailing whitespaces in URL

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-restcontroller

I've a very simple Spring MVC application, for example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/rest")
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/endpointA"}
    public @ResponseBody ResponseObject endpointA() {
        return something;
    }
}
```

The endpoint method should be mapped to the URL: "/rest/endpointA", but it is invoked also for "/%20rest/endpointA", "/rest   /endpointA" and any form of leading and/or trailing whitespaces.

Why is it, and is there a way to enforce an exact match of the URL to "/rest/endpointA", in terms of "/%20rest/endpointA" would result in a 404 Not Found response by Tomcat.

Thanks

Comment: See the link above, but depending on your version of Spring, the behavior/default setting of `trimTokens` in the ant path matcher may be different

Comment: tell me, why would you need that in the first place?

Comment: The hint to AntPathMatcher.trimTokens helped to sort this out, thank you.